# angular force trailing slash on default path

Tags: angular, trailing-slash

I want to force a trailing slash on default path.

I used as reference:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/angular-7-routing-with-preserving-trailing-slash-in-url/

My implementation works on every route except the default path ''.

In my app routing module I have:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'about/.',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/about-us/about-us.module').then(m => m.AboutUsModule)
  },
```

My links look like:

```
<a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]= "{exact: true}">Home</a></li>
<a routerLink="/about/." routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]= "{exact: true}">About</a></li>
```